# htaccess configure for routing in php and angularjs

Tags: php, .htaccess, angularjs, routes

So basically i want 2 folders in root one is server and the other is public.

Folder server is secured by always goto server/routes.php

Folder public is free to goto wherever if that file or dir exist.

If URL is **localhost/server(anything)** it goes to the **server/routes.php** with the URL **(anything)**

If URL is **localhost/(anything but server)** and (anything but server) is not a file or a dir in public it goes to the **public/index.html** with the URL **(anything but server)** otherwise if **(anything but server)** is a file or a dir in public it goes to public/(anything but server) i.e. (a file or a dir)

Some exmaples:

- localhost/server

  - server/routes.php
  - $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is empty
- localhost/server/users

  - server/routes.php
  - $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is **users**
- localhost/server/users?orderby=name

  - server/routes.php
  - $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is **users?orderby=name**
- localhost

  - url is empty
  - public/index.html
- localhost/users

  - url is users
  - public/index.html
- localhost/partials/users.html *(that file exist in public/partials/users.html)*

  - public/partials/users.html

How would I do this logic in .htaccess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place this `.hatccess` on the folder `server`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /server/

RewriteRule ^routes\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule . routes.php [L]
RewriteRule ^$ routes.php [L]
```

And place this `.htaccess` on the root folder of your domain:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -d [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

Give this 2 set of `.htaccess` a try and keep in mind that if you have tried anything else early using 301 redirects its advisable that you clear your browser cache or use a different browser that you haven't used to browse those sites to avoid the cache.

Comment: Wow thanks works perfectly. I noticed a problem with these set of rule which I asked for, that was a little hard to track down. If I were to load a file in index.html that does not exist it would cause a infinite loop(I guess), that hangs the browser. So I added **RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(.*)$** before first RewriteRule. It make sure that if I try to load a nonexistence file it will just pass RewriteCond and result in 404.

Comment: Well if you have access to the `httpd.conf` you can enable the rewritelog which makes debugging of rewrite rule very simple as you can also define the level of data it logs. So its easy to see where and why it fails.